# makefile for java, recompile only when files changed

Tags: java, makefile

I am learning how to write makefiles and ran into a problem.
I have a makefile for a java application but every time i execute the target jar, the whole code gets recompiled, even if nothing changed since the last call. I read often, that it is an advantage of make to only recompile, if dependencies of a target (e.g. 'jar') have changed, but it is not the case here. What can solve the problem?

```
FOLDER=some/path

jar: A.class B.class 
    jar cf output.jar  $(FOLDER)/bin/a/A.class $(FOLDER)/bin/b/B.class 

A.class: 
    javac $(FOLDER)/a/A.java -d $(FOLDER)/bin -implicit:none

B.class:
    javac $(FOLDER)/b/B.java -d $(FOLDER)/bin -implicit:none-implicit:none
```

Comment: Argh, use a build system that's *designed* for Java!  (Gradle, Maven, or even Ant.)

Comment: What does output.jar do, I hope it does not write to A.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit paths to your class files and don't forget the pre-requisite within the rule (the class depends on the Java source):

```
FOLDER=some/path

jar: $(FOLDER)/bin/a/A.class $(FOLDER)/bin/b/B.class
    jar cf output.jar  $(FOLDER)/bin/a/A.class $(FOLDER)/bin/b/B.class 

$(FOLDER)/bin/a/A.class: $(FOLDER)/a/A.java
    javac $(FOLDER)/a/A.java -d $(FOLDER)/bin -implicit:none

$(FOLDER)/bin/b/B.class: $(FOLDER)/b/B.java
    javac $(FOLDER)/b/B.java -d $(FOLDER)/bin -implicit:none-implicit:none
```

Comment: what would be the command for the target $(FOLDER)/bin/a/A.java ?

Comment: The *.java files dont need make targets/goals, those our sources isnt it ? What we do need taking care of is when those sources change their coressponded class files shoud be recompiled. Id suggest googling a little bit on make/makefiles, look for the terms target,goal,recipe.